# In Revelation 7:15 what does it mean that ὁ καθήμενος ἐπὶ τοῦ θρόνου σκηνώσει ἐπ’ αὐτούς?

Tags: greek, revelation

Does ὁ καθήμενος ἐπὶ τοῦ θρόνου σκηνώσει ἐπ’ αὐτούς suggest that in the new covenant, represented by the new tabernacle, all in the new covenant will dwell in God's inner courts?

Notes:

The reason I associate the new tabernacle is:

- Revelation is about the arrival of the new Jerusalem
- the new Jerusalem represents the new covenant:

> [Gal 4:24-26 KJV] 24 Which things are an allegory: for these are the two covenants; the one from the mount Sinai, which gendereth to bondage, which is Agar. 25 For this Agar is mount Sinai in Arabia, and answereth to Jerusalem which now is, and is in bondage with her children. 26 But Jerusalem which is above is free, which is the mother of us all.

- the tabernacle cannot represent the old covenant because that temple was judged and destroyed and the old covenant done away with - in 70AD.
- the tabernacle contained the ark of the old covenant and it was the basis of God's relations with Israel
- the new tabernacle must have the new covenant and it is the basis of God's relations with Israel (in the last days of the old covenant).

In fact, we have this explicitly explained in Hebrews:

> [Heb 8:5-6 KJV] 5 Who serve unto the example and shadow of heavenly things, as Moses was admonished of God when he was about to make the tabernacle: for, See, saith he, [that] thou make all things according to the pattern shewed to thee in the mount. 6 But now hath he obtained a more excellent ministry, by how much also he is the mediator of a better covenant, which was established upon better promises.

Exposition of the Greek: http://dailydoseofgreek.com/scripture-passage/revelation-7-15/

Comment: The 'new tabernacle' is imagery, revealed to John in vision. It isn't an actual building.

Answer (score 0):

This theme of being "overshadowed" by the LORD is a thread found elsewhere in scripture but I think that there is a particularly strong connection to Psalm 121:

> [Rev 7:15-16 DBY] 15 Therefore are they before the throne of God, and serve him day and night in his temple, and he that sits upon the throne **shall spread his tabernacle over them**. 16 They shall not hunger any more, neither shall they thirst any more, **nor shall the sun at all fall on them, nor any burning heat**;
>
> [Psa 121:5-8 KJV] 5 The LORD [is] thy keeper: **the LORD [is] thy shade upon thy right hand. 6 The sun shall not smite thee by day, nor the moon by night**. 7 The LORD shall preserve thee from all evil: he shall preserve thy soul. 8 The LORD shall preserve thy going out and thy coming in from this time forth, and even for evermore.

In a hot arid environment like the middle east, sunstroke is surely an issue. We know that all of humanity is like grass that withers. It is crucial to be shaded and have plenty of water to drink:

> [Isa 49:10 KJV] 10 They shall not hunger nor thirst; neither shall the heat nor sun smite them: for he that hath mercy on them shall lead them, even by the springs of water shall he guide them.

So I'm inclined to understand the figure of the LORD extending his tent over the Israel of God as protection from the elements etc. using "shade" as a metaphor.

The intended message then is one of encouragement to the elect/remnant of Israel that if they are martyred with Christ then all their troubles will be over.